# Scala: Mixing traits with private fields

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance, traits

It's not much of a question, it's rather my excitement that it's possible at all! I wrote this little example just to prove the opposite - I expected either a compiler error or one of the values (111 or 222, I wasn't sure).

```
scala> trait T1 { private val v = 111; def getValueT1 = v }
scala> trait T2 { private val v = 222; def getValueT2 = v }
scala> class T12 extends T1 with T2                        
scala> val t = new T12                                     
scala> t.getValueT1                                        
res9: Int = 111
scala> t.getValueT2                                        
res10: Int = 222
```

Why doesn't the `v` get overridden? Off course this works only as long as `v`s are private, but still.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since traits are not just interfaces, they need some way to store their internal state.  But they have to be compatible with interfaces--so what do they do?  They create accessors for what looks like a field (as you can see (among other things) with `javap -l -s -c -private` on the class files):

```
public interface T1 extends java.lang.Object {
public abstract int T1$$v();
Signature: ()I

public abstract int getValueT1();
Signature: ()I
}
```

and then create an implementation class that has static methods to implement the functionality:

```
public abstract class T1$class extends java.lang.Object {
public static int getValueT1(T1);
  Signature: (LT1;)I
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokeinterface #12,  1; //InterfaceMethod T1.T1$$v:()I
   6:   ireturn
}
```

Now, hopefully, it's clear that these would be separate by default since these internally-generated methods *have the name of the trait in the name of the method*.  And when we look in the implementation in `T12`:

```
public class T12 extends java.lang.Object implements T1,T2,scala.ScalaObject {
private final int Overridden$T1$$v;
  Signature: I

public final int T1$$v();
  Signature: ()I
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #22; //Field T1$$v:I
   4:   ireturn

public int getValueT1();
  Signature: ()I
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokestatic    #29; //Method T1$class.getValueT1:(LT1;)I
   4:   ireturn
}
```

you can see that it just fills in what's needed for each specific trait.  Now the question is--how do traits *ever* overwrite each other?  They seem to be completely separate!  That's the compiler's job.  If something is `private` it's hidden and can't be overridden, so it doesn't matter that another (private) thing has the same name.  But if it's not, the compiler complains of a collision:

```
error: overriding value v in trait T1 of type Int;
 value v in trait T2 of type Int needs `override' modifier
  class T12 extends T1 with T2
```

because now it's not using the secret mangled names with the trait name embedded.  (Observe that `getValueT1` is not mangled in this example.)

Comment: Nice answer. A slight correction - `T1$class` is called the implementation class.

Comment: Indeed--a companion class is something else.  Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a property particular to traits. For instance:

```
scala> class X {
     |   private val v = 111
     |   def getX = v
     | }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X {
     |   private val v = 222
     |   def getY = v
     | }
defined class Y

scala> new Y
res0: Y = Y@5ca801b0

scala> res0.getX
res1: Int = 111

scala> res0.getY
res2: Int = 222
```

And the same holds true in Java. Private members are *private*. They belong solely to where they were defined, and have no effect outside. If there was a conflict through inheritance, they would be visible, which would defeat the purpose of being private.

Comment: Now I'm a bit embarrassed to be so excited about such a trivial thing :)
I guess I just was too focused on traits to see the broader picture.

Comment: @Vilius Well, it _looks_ trivial from the Scala side. When one comes from Java, which is so full of limitations, it does look special.

Answer (score 1):

Private members and methods can't be overridden. It is to prevent changes in class behaviour injected by descendants. The concept here is very simlar to C++ one - each ancestor holds its own copy of members until a special methods (virtual inheritance, for example) is invoked.